# Inverse Laplace Transform via residues

Tags: inverse, laplace-transform, residue-calculus

I have $\frac{1}{2 \pi i} \int_{\infty-iT}^{\infty+iT} \frac{e^{-s(1-t)}-e^{st}}{-s+e^{-s}-1} ds$ and I am trying to solve it using a contour. So I could have t>0, or t<0. I have a pole at 0. For t<0 I got that is equal to 0 because I have a contour with no residue in it. For t>0 I have a contour with a vertical line on the positive side with a semicircle extending to the left to close it. So because the pole is inside, I expect the solution to be $2\pi i \sum residues$ where my residue is at 0.

So I have $2\pi i \frac{1}{2 \pi i} \frac{e^{-s(1-t)}-e^{st}}{-s+e^{-s}-1} (s-0)ds$. 
Which leaves me with $\frac{e^{-s(1-t)}-e^{st}}{-s+e^{-s}-1} s$ in the limit that s approaches 0. When I solve it I get 0. This doesn't seem right to me, so I am wondering if I am misunderstanding a part of it. Any help or direction is welcomed.

Comment: Do you mean to have your integration region go from $[T-i \infty,T+i \infty]$ instead?

Comment: meant to say $[\gamma -iT, \gamma +iT ]$

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the denominator is messy.  Rewrite your integrand as

$$\frac{1-e^{-s}}{1+s-e^{-s}} e^{s t}$$

There really is not a pole at $s=0$ because the singularity is removed by the numerator.  On the other hand, you may have zeroes in the complex plane - these are related to [Lambert's W-function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LambertW-Function.html) and may take some work to track down.  You will also need to worry about selecting a branch for those zeroes.  [Here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Table%5BN%5BProductLog%5Bk,E%5D-1%5D,%7Bk,0,10%7D%5D) is a table of some zeroes that correspond to a particular branch of the W-function.

Comment: I don't see why 0 wouldn't be a pole. If you have $1+s-e^{-s}$ and substitute s with 0, you have $1+0-e^0$ which is 0. Then with the complex zeros, I agree, I should have $s=\frac{W_n(e^tt)}{t}-1$, which either means I have an infinite number of poles or I missed something on the initial problem that I solved to get the posted problem.

Comment: Because the numerator is also zero at $s=0$ and in fact the fraction behaves at $s/(2 s) = 1/2$ as $s \to 0$.  Yes, you likely have an infinite number of poles.